# Maria DB fails to execute big query with too much data

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables, `customer` and `customer_risk_score`. The customer table grows when new customers are recorded. And I do an insert of customer data to customer_risk_score.

My scenario is I had over 245,890 entries in customer_risk_score Table and the customer entries had grown to 699,780 records.

When I run this query to

```
INSERT INTO customer_risk_score (rim, client_code, calculated_on)
  SELECT rim, client_type, Now()
  FROM customer
  WHERE rim NOT IN (SELECT rim FROM customer_risk_score)
```

via phpmyadmin, at that point when customer_risk_score has about 245,890 records and customer table having 699,780 ,the query runs forever No termination or error message. O tested it and waited for 3 hours then terminated it manually. I even reached on a point of killing all processes running on the DBMS via terminal by executing show processlist and it was the only process running.

When the customer_risk_score is truncated and i rerun the query, it takes about 3 seconds to insert the specific entries from the customer table to customer_risk_score.

This query is scheduled to run every two hours and my question would be what causes that delay. is it a bug in mariaDB version or my Query is designed in a wrong way? Am using MariaDB VERSION @@version
5.5.49-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks @Jarlh for editing my question. It got me a cool answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the `not in` subquery into a `left join ... is null` join and would make sure that the rim columns are indexed in both tables:

```
INSERT INTO customer_risk_score (rim, client_code, calculated_on)
  SELECT c.rim, c.client_type, Now()
  FROM customer c
  LEFT JOIN customer_risk_score crs on c.rim=crs.rim and crs.rim is null
```

The subquery in your original table quickly grows as more and more records are inserted into the customer_risk_score table. The join conditions in my proposed solution eliminate most of these records.

Another solution would be to use a `not exists` operator with subquery instead of the `not in`.

Comment: I tried your query with out indexing the columns and i manually terminated it at 7 minutes but when i indexed the columns it only took 14.73 seconds. Thanks Shadow

Comment: Without indexing the rim columns MySQL would be forced to scan the entire tables to match the records.

Answer (score 0):

@Shadow's solution was close, but had a fatal flaw.  This should work better:

```
INSERT INTO customer_risk_score (rim, client_code, calculated_on)
  SELECT c.rim, c.client_type, Now()
    FROM customer c
    LEFT JOIN customer_risk_score crs on c.rim=crs.rim
    WHERE crs.rim is null;   -- see note below
```

The check for `NULL` must not be in the `ON`; it must be in the `WHERE`.

And, yes, `rim` needs to be indexed.